# Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "

Tags: objective-c, macos, ios6, restkit-0.20

I am using restkit and am trying to hit https site from my simulator.
iPad simulator taking the system proxy while sending the request i guess and proxy blocked these request . 
Same code works fine when i run in iPad device.
Any one please help me.
Error i get is

```
I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:174 POST 'https://myurl.net/api/auth/entry'
2013-07-19 18:06:43.515 Dashboard[19149:4703] E    restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:570 Object request failed: Underlying HTTP request operation failed with error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x85806d0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Want to declare below line in Build setting pre process macros not use....... option
     _AFNETWORKING_ALLOW_INVALID_SSL_CERTIFICATES_